# Deserialize an MVC model not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deserialization

I have this model,

```
[Serializable]
    public class userMaster
    {
        public Step1_userName userName  { get; set; }
        public Step2_userAddress userAddress { get; set; }
        public Step3_userContact  userContact { get; set; } 
    }
```

I do a serialize on it in my view like this,

```
@Html.Hidden("RegMod",Model.Serialize())
```

I then post the data back to a controller action,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step1(Step1_userName userName, string RegMod)
    {
        var model = (userMaster)RegMod.Deserialize();
        model.userName = userName;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return View("Step2", model);
    }
```

I do get data in RegMod, but it will not deserialize back into an object. All I get is an empty (null) object. I also add new data to this object and that works fine.

Here is the Serialize/Deserialize class,

```
namespace MyMVCApplication
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {

        public static string Serialize(this object o)
        {
            var sw = new StringWriter(); 
            var formatter =  new LosFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(sw, o);

            return sw.ToString(); 
        }

        public static object Deserialize(this string data)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                return null; 

            var formatter = new LosFormatter();
            return formatter.Deserialize(data); 
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it does not deserialize, is there a better way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you de-/serializing the model and not use a hidden field for each property?

Comment: yes, Step1_userName and others are serializable.

Comment: @developer10214 I need to obsure the data in the hidden field.

Comment: @John - if you don't want the client to see the data, then I suggest not sending it to them in the first place.

Comment: @John - Can you please tell what is `LosFormatter` ?

Comment: @PankajGarg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter(v=vs.71).aspx?ppud=4

Answer (score 0):

I traced the problem to,

```
@Html.Hidden("RegMod",Model.Serialize())
```

The value of the hidden RegMod field is not the same as the value that came out of the serializer routine. so I tried this instead,

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.Serialize()" name="RegMod" />
```

and now it works.

It looks like the HTML helper was messing with the data.

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem, you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HenkMollema It will not let me for about 10 more hours.